# Postgresql Joining Time Series With Missing Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to outer join multiple time series tables in PostgreSQL on multiple conditions - which include the date column and several other identifier columns.

However the tables do not have continuous time series i.e. some dates are missing for some of the join conditions. Furthermore I don't want "duplicate" table specific new columns to be added for a row when there is not match

I have tried COALESCE() on the dates to fill in missing dates, which is fine. However it is the subsequent joins that are causing me problems. I also can't assume that one of the tables will have rows for all the dates required.

I thought perhaps to use generate series for a date range, with empty columns (? if possible) and then join all the tables on to that?

**Please see example below:**

I want to join Table A and Table B on *columns date*, *identifier_1* and *identifier_2* as an outer join. However where a value is not matched I do not want new columns to be added e.g. table_b_identifier_1.

**Table A**

**id1** and **id2** are missing rows on the 03/07 and 04/07, and **id1** is also missing a row for the 05/07.

[image]

**Table B**

**id2** is missing a row on the 02/07

[image]

**Desired Output:**

Essentially it is a conditional join. If there is a row in both tables for identifier_1 and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what is wrong with your attempt to use `COALESCE` to fill columns data, but it works well as intended in such a query

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.date, b.date) AS date,
    COALESCE(a.identifier_1, b.identifier_1) AS identifier_1,
    COALESCE(a.identifier_2, b.identifier_2) AS identifier_2,
    a.value_a,
    b.value_b
FROM table_a a
FULL JOIN table_b b ON a.date = b.date 
                       AND a.identifier_1 = b.identifier_1 
                       AND a.identifier_2 = b.identifier_2
```

Please, check a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5051d50467bb97ea99c4986761e2d187)

Comment: Brilliant thank you. The issue was that I was using COALESCE only on the date column. Once I added the identifier cols as per your reply it worked perfectly.